# parallelization level of Tupled RDD data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a RDD with the following type:

```
RDD[(Long, List(Integer))]
```

Can I assume that the entire list is located at the same worker? I want to know if certain operations are acceptable on the RDD level or should be calculated at driver. For instance:

```
val data: RDD[(Long, List(Integer))] = someFunction() //creates list for each timeslot
```

Please note that the `List` may be the result of `aggregate` or any other operation and not necessarily be created as one piece.

```
val diffFromMax = data.map(item => (item._1, findDiffFromMax(item._2)))

def findDiffFromMax(data: List[Integer]): List[Integer] = {
  val maxItem = data.max
  data.map(item => (maxItem - item))
}
```

The thing is that is the `List` is distributed calculating the `maxItem` may cause a lot of network traffic. This can be handles with an RDD of the following type:

```
RDD[(Long, Integer /*Max Item*/,List(Integer))]
```

Where the max item is calculated at driver.

So the question (actually 2 questions) are:

1. At what point of RDD data I can assume that the data is located at one worker? (answers with reference to doc or personal evaluations would be great) if any? what happens in the case of Tuple inside Tuple: `((Long, Integer), Double)`?
2. What is the common practice for design of algorithms with Tuples? Should I always treat the data as if it may appear on different workers? should I always break it to the minimal granularity at the first Tuple field - for a case where there is data(Double) for user(String) in timeslot(Long) - should the data be (Long, (Strong, Double)) or ((Long, String), Double) or maybe (String, (Long, Double))? or maybe this is not optimal and matrices are better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, your list would be located in a single worker.

Your tuple is a single record in the RDD. A single record is ALWAYS on a single partition (which would be on a single worker).
When you do your findDiffFromMax you are running it on the target worker (so the function is serialized to all the workers to run).

The thing you should note is that when you generate a tuple of (k,v) in general this means a key value pair so you can do key based operations on the RDD. The order ( (Long, (Strong, Double)) vs.  ((Long, String), Double) or any other way) doesn't really matter as it is all a single record. The only thing that would matter is which is the key in order to do key operations so the question would be the logic of your calculation

Comment: Thx for the explanation. what in the case where instead of a List there is ParArray? it doesn't matter since its still in the Tuple which is a single record? if my case was RDD[ParArray[(Long, Integer)]] would every ParArray be a single record?

Comment: Another question is since its key-val pairs, can I say that *ALL* the tuples with the same first element in the Tuple will be located together? I mean can I use join without reshuffling?

Comment: in this respect RDD is defined as RDD[T] where T is the record type and the record is always in a single partition. if you choose T to be ParArray[(Long, Integer) then it would be a single record. Of course if the record is too large you would probably just get an OOM exception or similar issue so don't over do it.

Comment: toda for the explanation.

Comment: When you start, there is no explicit correlation. If you do GroupByKey then all elements of the key would appear in a single partition. If you do a reduceByKey then the reduction would occur in each partition and then the results would be merged in the final partition.